# Cast as char/varchar

Tags: sql, casting, teradata

I'm trying to convert this SQL syntax from casting as `DATE` to `CHAR/VARCHAR`. Can you please provide any suggestions?

```
xyz(CAST((mth||'-'||SUBSTRING(TRIM(mth_yr+50) FROM 2 FOR 2)||'-25')  AS DATE), -1) /50+ 2000 ) abc123;
```

I have tried substituting `DATE` with `CHAR/VARCHAR` as below, but I was not successful :

```
xyz(CAST((mth||'-'||SUBSTRING(TRIM(mth_yr+50) FROM 2 FOR 2)||'-25')  AS char(50)), -1) /50+ 2000 ) abc123;
```

Should the `char(50)` go after `(mth_yr+50)`?

Comment: what good would that do?even  if it was legal syntax, you'd be basically saying "substring returns a string", which is a "no duh" situation.

Comment: Can you provide an example of what the data looks like, plus what you want it to look like after the conversion?

Comment: @datagod, This is part of a view and right now its displaying as an integer for that field "abc123" and the reporting team wants that field to be displayed as a char/varchar for easier joins I believe.

Comment: Looks like I figured it out. I had to add another cast statement before xyz to cast the entire field as char.

Comment: What you do looks overly complicated. What's the actual data in `mth` and `mth_yr` and what's the result of this strange calculation?